# Sonar reports JaCoCo Coverage for the Test classes themselves. Is this correct? How do I change this?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, eclipse-pde, multi-module, jacoco

we have a multi-module Maven project of Eclipse Plugins.

Code Coverage Report generation using JaCoCo is working, but the statistics seem to be false.

Coverage of the test classes themselves is being calculated AND being added to the general code coverage percentage.

Example:

- A plugin called org.myplugin has coverage 50% and 100 lines of code.
- The test plugin called org.myplugin.tests has coverage 100% and 100 lines of code.
- The general code coverage percentage amounts to 75% or 150 lines of code.

This is of course not really correct, because what is important is that the coverage is really only 50% of the normal code.

Is this normal behaviour? What can I do to exclude the coverage for the test classes?

EDIT: Here are the relevant parts of several of our POM files:

Project POM:

```
<groupId>de.tool</groupId>
<artifactId>toolname</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <tycho-version>0.13.0</tycho-version>
    <junit-version>4.8.2</junit-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jacoco-maven-version>0.5.6.201201232323</jacoco-maven-version>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
<!--    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>../${project.artifactId}.tests/target/surefire-reports/</sonar.surefire.reportsPath> -->
</properties>


<modules>
    <module>de.tool.plugin</module>
    <module>de.tool.plugin.tests</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.basedir}/../../target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Plugin POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>de.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>toolname</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.tool.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>de.tool.plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
```

Test Plugin POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>de.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>toolname</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <relativePath>../../plugins</relativePath>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.tool.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>de.tool.plugin.tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In jenkins (emma plugin) if the name of package was in two different modules only one was included to final report. Check reports for each module separate and count yourself - maybe it is bug in sonar.

Comment: Can you show your POM? Using JaCoCo in a multi-module project works perfectly out of the box, so there's certainly something wrong with configuration on your side.

Comment: Well, I've never tried to get unit test and coverage reports for Eclipse plugins with Sonar, so I might miss some pieces of your context. But some stuff seem strange to me:

Comment: (continuing my previous comment...)

1/ the "sonar.jacoco.reportPath" property with its "../..": why do you try to find the results there? because you generate this report separetely?

2/ the fact that tests are in a separate module (I don't know Sonar can handle this actually). If you actually generate the coverage report separately, maybe you will get real coverage if you exclude "de.tool.plugin.tests" during Sonar analysis.

Comment: 1) I generate the JaCoCo report results during the Jenkins build. The Maven JaCoCo plugin does this. I collect the results in a single result file in the parent project of all modules so that every module can put their result in the same file.

Comment: 2) Sonar doesn't really need to handle separate test plugins, does it? The JaCoCo report contains all information that Sonar needs to display the coverage...or doesn't it?
How do I exclude a plugin during Sonar JaCoCo analysis?
As I understand the agent collects during the Jenkins/Maven Build phase. Can I exclude report parts for certain modules?

Comment: I'm just asking because I want to exclude code coverage for test plugins, but not findbugs, checkstyle etc. for those test plugins.